# Database name containd dot in jdbc url spring boot

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-data

Dear all I am in the unfortunate sitution to connect to an sqlserver 2005 databae that was provided to me and contains o dot (.)

I have setup a configuration for spring boot like

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username("myuname")
        .password("mypass")
        .url("jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.10:1433;databaseName=REALLY_BAD_NAME_V3.5;")
        .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        .build();
  }

}
```

And of course I get an exception stating `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Database '5' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

I have tried in vain the following

`.url("jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.10:1433;databaseName={REALLY_BAD_NAME_V3.5};")`

that gives the same error and

`.url("jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.10:1433;databaseName=REALLY_BAD_NAME_V3{.}5;")`

And gives a malformed url exception after reading [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dot with a backslash: `\.` or URL-encoding it?

Comment: Use escape character as suggested by cjstehno

Comment: url encoding does not work and \. throws compilation error. Any other idea?

Comment: Try a double backslash \\

Comment: Did didnt work either
Cannot open database "REALLY_BAD_NAME__V3\.5" requested by the login

Comment: Which driver/version do you use? sqljdbc_4.2.6420.100 and sqljdbc_6.0.6629.101 work quite nicely (except they are not available in Maven Central).